# Primefaces interface test on pc?

Tags: jsf, primefaces, interface

I am developing a web application with a mobile interface using JSF/Primefaces and I want to test the change from one view to another but the only view that appears is the first one.

How to make it work on PC?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use Mozilla Firefox you can download a plugin called **User Agent Switcher**. There you go to tools -> Default user Agent -> By default it shows Iphone 3.0, but you can download more agents to render different browser views.

[You can learn some about the User Agents here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/User_agent)

Comment: Thanks for your reply, i found an error in the code that is related to view referencing.I i resolved the problem and downloaded firesizer wich helps to change the screen dimension easily. I'll check out User Agent Switcher, i seems to be a great solution too.
Thanks.